# VSCode: Freezes after compilation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to compile VSCode source for the first time ever, I ran the "yarn run watch" command and eventually the compilation finished with the message "Finished Compilation with 0 errors" but then the console just gets stuck there. I tried using different consoles but still facing the same problem.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see your yarn commands.

Comment: Did you solve the problem !? @StefanCrain The command is `yarn run watch`

Answer (score 0):

**I killed the process and had no later problems using VS Code from this build.**

In the directory where vscode was cloned, I checked with `du -s` that nothing was changing over a few minutes of testing will the logging was stopped on your message above.

Having stopped `yarn run watch` I then carried out the next instruction of the build process: `yarn watch`.

This also hung with the same message. I used `du` again. And again there was no change in the size of the directory. I stopped `yarn watch` and was then able to run vscode, editing files without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

All custom commands like `watch` that you can `yarn run` are defined in the file `package.json` in the project root. In this case, it's [package.json on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/package.json). Even before looking at it, I assumed from the name that what the command does is probably to build once and then go into a loop that watches for new changes and then rebuilds. In the section called `scripts` of `package.json` we see that `watch` is defined to be `gulp watch --max_old_space_size=4095`. Google gulp watch, and [you'll see](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)  that that's what it does.

I think you're looking for `yarn run compile`, which the vscode team setup to build the project once and then exit.